# Broadcom Wireless Drivers [14e4:4331] (rev 02) Macbook Pro Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, wireless, broadcom, macbook-pro

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my old Macbook Pro, Everything is working great except for the wireless driver.

`lspci -nn -d 14e4:` gets the following:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
```

`lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network` gets:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:00f5]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 256 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 0
    Region 0: Memory at a0600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

`rfkill list all` gets:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`grep b43 /etc/modprobe.d/*` gets:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf:blacklist b43
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf:blacklist b43legacy
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:# replaced by b43 and ssb.
```

and `sudo dmesg | grep b43` does not get anything in return.

I found this great [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/60395/1109113) on how to install Broadcom Wireless Drivers, and have tried the `firmware-b43-installer` package and the `linux-firmware` option, but it does not work in my case, as after installing the package and reboot, the system still cannot detect a wifi adapter.

As the great post mentioned that if my Broadcom card has a different pci.id that cannot be found in the list, I can ask a new question. So here I am.

Many thank.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `rfkill list all` and: `grep b43 /etc/modprobe.d/*` and: `sudo dmesg | grep b43` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Great thanks for your kind responce, I have updated the question as per instruction. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf:blacklist b43

It appears that you attempted to install another driver which blacklists the driver *b43* which is needed for your device. Let's correct it:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf
sudo modprobe b43
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: I think it's better to remove the package `bcmwl-kernel-source` that probably provided that file.

Comment: @Pilot6 If it were installed, it would have claimed his device. I think the problem is just that; that he removed it but should have *purged* it.

Comment: Awesome! It works now! Thanks a lot :P